# Generate unique permutation pairs in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array:

```
$arr = [];
$arr['One'] = 1;
$arr['Two'] = 2;
$arr['Three'] = 3;
$arr['Four'] = 4;
$arr['Five'] = 5;
$arr['Six'] = 6;
```

From which i'd like to generate permutation pairs with it's keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$result = generatePermutations($keys);
```

Where `$result` would be an array of arrays of unique pairs:

```
//as per example, $result =
$result = [[['One','Two'],['Three','Four'],['Five','Six']],
           [['One','Three'],['Two','Four'],['Five','Six']],
           [['One','Four'],['Two','Three'],['Five','Six']],
           [['One','Five'],['Two','Three'],['Four','Six']],
           [['One','Two'],['Three','Five'],['Four','Six']],
           [['One','Three'],['Two','Five'],['Four','Six']],
           [['One','Six'],['Two','Three'],['Four','Five']],
           [['One','Two'],['Three','Six'],['Four','Five']],
           etc..
          ];
```

I found multiple ways to generate permutations, yet most of them didn't focus specifically on pairs and a lot of them put all the permutations in a single array.

Comment: You be lucky to find a coded solution which handles pairs, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried generating them, but ended up with combinations not permutations

Comment: does the source array need to be like that? `$arr = ['One','Two','Three','Four'];` would make life easier

Comment: I am curious what your expected result is when you add 'Five' and 'Six' to the input array.  Do you want 3 pairs per subarray?  Can you post your expected output for this scenario? (just enough array structure to clarify this point, please)  I think the accepted answer does a fair job on One-Four, but I think the One-Six result should look different, no?

Comment: @mickmackusa Looks fine to me. What do you reckon it should look like? I understood it as OP needed to calculate every unique combination, and then make *every* possible unique pair between the resulting combinations. Obviously there are a **lot** more of those when you go from 4 to 6 elements.

Comment: @ishegg This is what I am thinking:  For One-Four: `[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,3],[2,4]],[[1,4],[2,3]]`
For One-Six: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[1,3],[2,5],[4,6]],[[1,4],[2,6],[3,5]],[[1,5],[2,4],[3,6]],[[1,6],[2,3],[4,5]]`  3-pairs per deep subarry.  No?

Comment: Hm that certainly is a possibility but OP explicitly stated “pairs” which is why I went with my answer.

Comment: @ishegg Yes, I understand that perspective and I like your answer.  Unfortunately the term "pairs" is a little too ambiguous with One-Four.  This is why I want to clarify.  If it is meant to be a max of two deep subarrays per row of numbers then that output looks different again -- it would be a pair of 3-element subarrays.

Comment: I see. Agreed. How would it be though? Groups of `n/2` elements? Let’s wait for OP.

Comment: @mickmackusa - What you described for one-six is what i actually want, yes.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify and i see that @ishegg proposed solution does no comply to that, can you make an edit?

Comment: @Banana I am really loving this challenge.  But let me clarify-- what you have posted in your question is different that what I posted.  `['Five','Six']` is the 3rd subarray for your first three data sets.  My version had just 5 total sets of data using `One`-`Six`, but yours will have far more.  This is important information to iron out before developing the code.

Comment: Hey mickmausa, good to hear you're loving the challenge, sorry, i'm currently a bit sick and it was a long day when i was reading your comment.  The example written in my post is the one i'm hoping to achieve. Basically all the possible permutations which can happen with these numbers need to be included as a group of pairs in this array, each group being obviously unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to call this a "working solution" at best.  It is certainly possible that I have redundant filters or wasted iterations, but I've been developing and debugging this for too many hours now and I'm no longer sharp.  If/When I discover ways to refined this code block (or someone offers a suggestion) I will update my answer.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e878b0a5f4f1e89c60f0f04a4f4391ac704e16b))

```
function pairedPerms($arr){
    $val1=$arr[0];
    $pairs_per_set=sizeof($arr)/2;
    foreach($arr as $v1){  // $arr is preserved/static
        $arr=array_slice($arr,1);  // modify/reduce second foreach's $arr
        foreach($arr as $v2){
            if($val1==$v1){
                $first[]=[$v1,$v2];  // unique pairs as 2-d array containing first element
            }else{
                $other[]=[$v1,$v2]; // unique pairs as 2-d array not containing first element
            }            
        }
    }

    for($i=0; $i<$pairs_per_set; ++$i){  // add one new set of pairs per iteration
        if($i==0){
            foreach($first as $pair){
                $perms[]=[$pair]; // establish an array of sets containing just one pair
            }
        }else{
            $expanded_perms=[];
            foreach($perms as $set){
                $values_in_set=[];  // clear previous data from exclusion array
                array_walk_recursive($set,function($v)use(&$values_in_set){$values_in_set[]=$v;}); // exclude pairs containing these values
                $candidates=array_filter($other,function($a)use($values_in_set){
                    return !in_array($a[0],$values_in_set) && !in_array($a[1],$values_in_set);
                });
                if($i<$pairs_per_set-1){
                    $candidates=array_slice($candidates,0,sizeof($candidates)/2);  // omit duplicate causing candidates
                }
                foreach($candidates as $cand){
                    $expanded_perms[]=array_merge($set,[$cand]); // add one set for every new qualifying pair
                }
            }
            $perms=$expanded_perms;  // overwrite earlier $perms data with new forked data
        }
    }
    return $perms;
}
//$arr=['One'=>1,'Two'=>2];
//$arr=['One'=>1,'Two'=>2,'Three'=>3,'Four'=>4];
$arr=['One'=>1,'Two'=>2,'Three'=>3,'Four'=>4,'Five'=>5,'Six'=>6];
//$arr=['One'=>1,'Two'=>2,'Three'=>3,'Four'=>4,'Five'=>5,'Six'=>6,'Seven'=>7,'Eight'=>8];
$result=pairedPerms(array_keys($arr));
//var_export($result);

echo "[\n";
foreach($result as $sets){
    echo "\t[ ";
    foreach($sets as $pairs){
        echo "[",implode(',',$pairs),"]";
    }
    echo " ]\n";
}
echo "]";
```

Output:

```
[
    [ [One,Two][Three,Four][Five,Six] ]
    [ [One,Two][Three,Five][Four,Six] ]
    [ [One,Two][Three,Six][Four,Five] ]
    [ [One,Three][Two,Four][Five,Six] ]
    [ [One,Three][Two,Five][Four,Six] ]
    [ [One,Three][Two,Six][Four,Five] ]
    [ [One,Four][Two,Three][Five,Six] ]
    [ [One,Four][Two,Five][Three,Six] ]
    [ [One,Four][Two,Six][Three,Five] ]
    [ [One,Five][Two,Three][Four,Six] ]
    [ [One,Five][Two,Four][Three,Six] ]
    [ [One,Five][Two,Six][Three,Four] ]
    [ [One,Six][Two,Three][Four,Five] ]
    [ [One,Six][Two,Four][Three,Five] ]
    [ [One,Six][Two,Five][Three,Four] ]
]
```

Comment: @Banana Okay, I think I cracked it.  If something isn't right let me know.  My brain has turned to mush for the moment, so you should DEFINITELY check my work.  If I manage to improve its speed or memory usage, I will ping you so you can update your project.

Comment: Yeah, i see some refinements to make.  I'll update when I can.

Comment: Hey @mickmackusa, thank you for your answer, from the memory usage i have no suggestions, but the permutations you're making seem to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through them twice to generate the unique combinations, then iterate through the combinations to form the unique pairs:

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$arr['One'] = 1;
$arr['Two'] = 2;
$arr['Three'] = 3;
$arr['Four'] = 4;

function generatePermutations($array) {
    $permutations = [];
    $pairs = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($array as $key2 => $value2) {
            if ($key === $key2) continue;
            $permutations[] = [$key, $key2];
        }
        array_shift($array);
    }
    foreach ($permutations as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($permutations as $key2=>$value2) {
            if (!in_array($value2[0], $value) && !in_array($value2[1], $value)) {
                $pairs[] = [$value, $value2];
            }
        }
        array_shift($permutations);
    }
    return $pairs;
}
print_r(generatePermutations($arr));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Slc7j)

Comment: upvoting this, no recursion and gives the right result (even extending the array to Five, Six... etc.)

Comment: Hey @ishegg, i edited my question to give more clearance on how i'm expecting to get the results.

Comment: @Banana I made a "three per array" version for 6 elements (you can see it [here](https://3v4l.org/BRufq)), but it won't work for 2, 4, 5, etc. What I mean is, you need to give your exact requisites so as to make a generalized version of the function, so it works with **n** elements, not just with any fixed number. In other words, tell us what you need "for all n elements".

Comment: Hey ishegg, sorry if im not explaining myself in the best way. Basically if you take n amount, the result should evaluate always into array which contains arrays which each of contain a pair. In a same way as with 6, if you'd add n amount of numbers where `n%2==0`. So with 8 the first array would be `[[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]],[[1,3],[2,4],[5,6],[7,8]],etc..]`. So each two numbers would add one more pair to the inner arrays. Pretty difficult to explain and to visualise as with larger element amount the arrays get pretty big but i hope you'll understand. And i do need a solution for n elements.

Comment: And when there's an odd number of elements?

Comment: There's no odd amount of elements, that's filtered out before and cannot happen!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
    $arr = [];
    $arr['One'] = 1;
    $arr['Two'] = 2;
    $arr['Three'] = 3;
    $arr['Four'] = 4;

    foreach($arr as $key1=>$val1) {
        foreach($arr as $key2=>$val2) {
            if($val1>$val2) continue;
            if($key1 !== $key2) {
                echo "[$key1, $key2], ";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is close what i'd like to achieve, but this takes ['One','Two'] and ['Two','One'] as different permutations and still shows them (though they should be the same)

Comment: Try with this IF statement in inner loop: if($val1>$val2) continue; I'll edit the answer...

Comment: This gets the permutation, but not in unique pairs (just returns all the permutation of pairs)

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the problem, you can divide it into two parts.

Firstly, generate all combinations. You can use the following function for that (the idea came from [Tom Butler's post](https://r.je/php-find-every-combination.html)):

```
function getCombinations(array $array)
{
    $num = count($array); 
    $total = pow(2, $num);

    for ($i = 1; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $combination = [];
        for ($j = 0; $j < $num; $j++) {
            if (pow(2, $j) & $i) {
                $combination[$j] = $array[$j];
            }
        }

        yield $combination;
    }
}
```

Then you can filter all combinations and keep only those with two elements in them:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$result = array_filter(
    iterator_to_array(getCombinations($keys)),
    function ($combination) {
        return count($combination) === 2;
    }
);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d72e8e05022049d1cc14ceae1da9788d5b190429).

Comment: This gives all the permutation pairs, but not uniquely or 'dependant'. Please see my question on expected output.

Answer (score -3):

In python it's as easy as

```
result = itertools.permutations(keys, 2)
```

If you want to do it from scratch algorithmic-ally, you could implement a recursive function like this. I've written something pretty naive in python, sorry it's not PHP.

```
// permutation function
def permutations(my_list, target_len, curr_perm):
  // base case
  if len(curr_perm) = target_len:
    print(curr_perm)
    return

  for item in my_list:
    // don't add duplicates
    if item in curr_perm:
      continue

    next_perm = curr_perm.copy()
    next_perm.append(item)
    // recursive call 
    permutations(my_list, target_len, next_perm)


// generate permutations of length 2
permutations(['one', 'two', 'three'], 2, [])
```

Comment: Yes, that's why i asked my question about PHP :)

Comment: I was afraid that if I gave you PHP code, you'd copy and paste it without understanding it. I wrote it in an easy to understand language, so that you could easily translate it, and hopefully understand it.